# Insert a new line in a large paragraph

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is about adding a new line in a paragraph.  I have a large paragraph of around 10 lines which is between `<p> </p>` tags.  I want to split the paragraph at the 5th line. how do i do that?  I have tried `</n>` but it doesn't work. 
I have even tried looking through he solutions provided here.

Comment: Is this only about HTML? If so, then you need a ```<br>``` tag.

Comment: "<br/>" if it's html

Comment: <br> and <br /> do the same in HTML, it's just HTML vs XHTML.

Comment: Use br twice: `<br><br>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `</n>` you should try `<br>` to create a line break in HTML.

To create an empty line, you need 2 `<br>` tags.

The better solution would be to create 2 separate paragraph sections with two `<p>` blocks.